# ListView in a pop up window

Tags: android, listview, popup

I am making an application and using a custom adapter for ListView. It is working in the activity

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    int resourceID;
    ArrayList<String> names;
    public Adapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.resourceID=resource;
        this.names= objects;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return names.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        row = inflater.inflate(resourceID, parent, false);

        TextView text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);

        text.setText(names.get(position));
        return row;
    }

}
```

I used this code to make them appear on an activity

```
    myNames= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List);
    adapter = new Adapter(this,R.layout.names_view, Current.Names);
    myNames.setAdapter(adapter);
```

now I want to click on a button to make the same list appear on a popup, any help?

Comment: A popup is an AlertDialog or what do you mean?

Comment: i mean this class PopupWindow was trying to do it multiple ways but it didn't work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may do as following:

1) Create a custom dialog on button click:

```
Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickButton);
clickButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Title...");
            myNames= (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.List);
            adapter = new Adapter(YourActivity.this,R.layout.names_view, Current.Names);
            myNames.setAdapter(adapter);
            dialog.show();

        }
    });
```

2)Add the listview in the dialog layout (custom_dialog.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <ListView
      android:id="@+id/List"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you so much, it worked , but instead of "this" i used "Activity.this" and dialog.show() in the end

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes. I've corrected my answer. If it helped you may mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: Done :) , but change the other this too

Answer (score 4):

custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</ListView>
```

activity

```
String names[] ={"A","B","C","D"};
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
                alertDialog.setView(convertView);
                alertDialog.setTitle("List");
                ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.List);
                Adapter<String> adapter = new Adapter(this,R.layout.names_view, Current.Names);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: thanks it worked perfectly , but to have it when i clicked a button i replaced  "this" in "Adapter<String> adapter = new Adapter(this,R.layout.names_view, Current.Names);" to "MainActivity.this"

Comment: Welcome... Happy to help @E.Khaled

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom dialog

custom dialog mydialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Activity.this);
   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mydialog)
ListView lv = (ListView ) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lv);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.setTitle("ListView");
dialog.show();
```

Comment: what does dialog.setCancelable(true); do ?

Comment: user wont to able to the dismiss the dialog by press back key or tapping on screen only he can press the dialog button to make disappear

Answer (score 1):

I typed "PopupWindow" into google and found this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fn5OlqQuOCk

I didn't knew the PopupWindow until now and I'd recommend to use a dialog e.g. AlertDialog with a costum view.

I hope I could help!

Comment: thank u so much for trying to help , i used Dialog and it really worked